# How to match CRC32 algorithms working on various data sizes

Tags: c, arm, stm32, crc, crc32

I have a device that adds a CRC32 checksum to data it sends. It is calculated using a lookup table as follows:

```c
uint32_t CrcFromBuffer(uint8_t* buffer, uint16_t lenght) {
    uint32_t crc32 = 0xffffffff;

    if (buffer == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        while (lenght != 0) {
            uint8_t crc32_table_index = ((uint8_t)(crc32) ^ (*buffer));
            crc32 = crc32 >> 8;
            crc32 = crc32_table[crc32_table_index] ^ crc32;
            buffer++;
            lenght--;
        }
    }

    return ~crc32;
}
```

I'm using an STM32F401 microcontroller, which has hardware support for calculating CRC with the same polynomial but only with a 32-bit input data size. It works fine if the data length is a multiple of 4 bytes. Here's an example:

```c
bool eight_bytes_random_crc() {
  uint8_t array8[8] = {0xAB, 0x21, 0x32, 0x47, 0x01, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x99};
  uint32_t array32[2] = {__RBIT(0x473221AB), __RBIT(0x9900FF01)}; // need to reverse bit order
  uint32_t hard_crc = __RBIT(~HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, array32, 2)); // again reverse bits and negate the result
  uint32_t soft_crc = CrcFromBuffer(array8, 8); 
  return hard_crc == soft_crc; 
}
```

How can I use the STM32 hardware CRC support for data arrays with a length that is not a multiple of 4 bytes?

I tried a brute-force search for a value that would produce the same CRC for a single byte but couldn't find an obvious way to get that value, given only the 0xAB input:

```c
uint32_t one_byte_crc() {
  uint8_t array8[1] = {0xAB};
  uint32_t soft_crc = CrcFromBuffer(array8, 1); 
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= 0xFFFFFFFF; i++ ) {
      uint32_t array32[1] = {__RBIT(i)};
      uint32_t hard_crc = __RBIT(~HAL_CRC_Calculate(&hcrc, array32, 1));
      if (hard_crc == soft_crc) {
        return i; // gives 0xF7D1D97E
      }
  }    
}
```

Any suggestions on how to use STM32 hardware CRC for non-multiple of 4 byte length data arrays?

Comment: Why not use the hardware to calculate the CRC on all but the last 0 to 3 bytes, and then use software to finish off the CRC on those last few bytes?

Comment: @MarkAdler The CRC calculation are a part of bootloader with very limited space for program binary. The main reason I was looking into hardware solution was to get rid of 1kB lookup table. But I might go with "algorithmic" calculations of the last 3 bytes, that might do the trick.

Comment: You don't need the table if you're ok with more instructions per byte. What is the polynomial? If you don't know, what is the 129th entry of the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do is either a) use the hardware to calculate the CRC up to a multiple of four bytes of your data, and then use software to finish up the CRC with the last 0 to 3 bytes, or b) use the hardware to calculate the CRC of all of your data padded out to a multiple of four with zeros, and then use a reverse CRC table to un-calculate the last 0 to 3 zeros from the CRC.

The most efficient might be to use a) if there are 0 or 1 bytes left, and b) if there are 3 bytes left, so un-calculating 1 byte. For 2 bytes left, you'd pick the faster one, but I'm not sure which one that would be. Could go either way.

Comment: The linked answer will not work. It is designed for the STM32G family, which supports byte, half-word and word CRC operations. The STM32F family only supports word-size (32 bit) operations.

Comment: Accepting the answer despite the bottom line was "not possible". For completeness sake - I solved a problem by generating the lookup table on the initialization - I was having issues only with flash memory, but had plenty of RAM available.